# How to apply multiple functions to several chunks of a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, dask

I have a dataframe of 500,000 lines and 3 columns. I would like to compute the result of three functions for every chunk of 5,000 lines in the dataframe (that is, 100 chunks). Two of the three functions are used-defined, while the third is the mean of the values in column 3.

At the moment, I am first extracting a chunk, and then computing the results of the functions for that chunk. For the mean of column 3 I am using `df.iloc[:,2].compute().mean()` but the other functions are performed outside of dask.

Is there a way to leverage dask's multithreading ability, taking the entire dataframe and a chunk size as input, and have it computing the same functions but automatically? This feels like the more appropriate way of using Dask.

Also, this feels like a basic dask question to me, so please if this is a duplicate, just point me to the right place (I'm new to dask and I might have not looked for the right thing so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would repartition your dataframe, and then use the map_partitions function to apply each of your functions in parallel

```
df = df.repartition(npartitions=100)
a = df.map_partitions(func1)
b = df.map_partitions(func2)
c = df.map_partitions(func3)

a, b, c = dask.compute(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an artificial column for grouping indices into those 100 chunks.

```
ranges = np.arange(0, df.shape[0], 5000)
df['idx_group'] = ranges.searchsorted(df.index, side='right')
```

Then use this idx_group to perform your operations using pandas groupby.

**NOTE:** You can play with [searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to exactly fit your chunk requirements.